# URL masking of subdomain to main domain using .htaccess

Tags: redirect, urls, htaccess

I am facing with the following technical challenge : We have a main website running on wordpress with content in local language (Greek) on the domain www.adomain.gr

We want to set up a second website running wordpress (different sidebars etc) that will show the English language content running on a subdomain:

`english.adomain.gr`

We would like that if someone goes to the english.adomain.gr by cliking a link from, for example, the main site, the url is masked as the main site - e.g. `english.adomain.gr/post` will show `www.adomain.gr/post`

I know that .htaccess helps but do not know how.

Any guidance ?